# Excel remove timestamp from date and subtract days

Tags: excel

So I have a column say Date1 which has date in datetime stamp. I want to subtract 10 days from Date1 column and keep in another column say Date2. I only want to subtract ten days from date not from datetime.

How to remove the time stamp. Read many solutions online but could not find for excel

**Input table**

```
 Date1                     
26-03-2000 21:00:00 
25-04-2000 00:00:00
21-03-2000 01:00:00
31-03-2000 13:00:00
05-03-2012 12:00:00
```

**Expected output**

```
Date1                    Date2       Date1_no_timestamp
26-03-2000 21:00:00     16-03-2000   26-03-2000
25-04-2000 00:00:00     15-04-2000   25-04-2000 
21-03-2000 01:00:00     11-03-2000   21-03-2000
31-03-2000 13:00:00     21-03-2000   31-03-2000
05-03-2012 12:00:00     24-02-2012   05-03-2012   and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the TEXT() function.

`=TEXT(B2, "DD-MM-YYYY")`

Alternatively, as the above solution could cause issue based on timezone formatting, you could remove anything past the first space:

`=LEFT(B2, FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)`

Place either the following in C2 (assuming those headers exist) and drag down.

Comment: Makes no sense. You want to return the answer in the cell or Sub you are in.
Why B2 and A2? Can you re-write this to output in current location? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

**Method 1:**

- Date1_no_timestamp:

`=TEXT(A2,"dd-mm-yyyy")`

- Date2:

`=TEXT(A2-10,"dd-mm-yyyy")`

**Method 2**

- Date1_no_timestamp:

`=RIGHT("0"&DAY(A2),2)&"-"&RIGHT("0"&MONTH(A2),2) & "-" & YEAR(A2)`

- Date2:

`=TEXT(DATEVALUE(E2)-10,"dd-mm-yyyy")`

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Strange... =Text(DateValue(E2)-10,"dd-mm-yyyy") Never works for me! DateValue just seems bogus... Returns "#VALUE!" ???

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **INT()** and **TRUNC()** functions:

`=INT(A2)`

`=TRUNC(A2)`

Their behavior is identical for positive numbers - the decimal part is sliced off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nope. Neither work. CELL = 1/02/2023  12:00:00 AM, then  INT(A2) = 1/02/2023 00:00:00 and TRUNC(A2): 1/02/2023 00:00:00